# How can I use autolayout and wrap multiple UI Labels in a row?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a UITableViewCell subclass that displays 7 pieces of information, one label across the top showing the entity name, and then 6 labels with the entity's data. When in portrait, I want the cell to look like:

```
    | Entity Name                     |
    | [data1]     [data2]     [data3] |
    | [data4]     [data5]     [data6] |
```

And in landscape I want the cell to look like:

```
    | Entity Name                                          |
    | [data1]  [data2]  [data3]  [data4]  [data5]  [data6] |
```

I can accomplish either independently with Autolayout, but is what is the best way to accomplish both? Is there a way to do this with a single set of constraints or should I be removing/adding all the necessary NSLayoutConstraints each time the device is rotated, or is there some other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I would take for this is to use a UICollectionView inside the cell.

That way the layout of the cell is managed by something that is used to doing this kind of thing and it won't matter how many labels you add if you decide to add some in the future.

Make the cell a UICollectionViewDelegate / Datasource so that each cell manages its own layout.

Comment: Is there a way to do that with UICollectionViewFlowLayout, or would I need to implement my own layout class?  I am not yet super familiar with the collection view.  It looks like I would set the scrollDirection to Vertical, but then keep a constraint on the collection view's height around and make it larger/smaller depending on the number of rows I expect (so that it doesn't scroll at all) ?

Comment: Indeed, this worked perfectly.   Had to keep a constraint around to track & reset the UICollectionView's height (size to fit content), but that was much easier than expected.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. To answer your other comment, yes just use flow layout. But you probably already did that :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are two method works.

1. Use UICollectionView, flow layout is its default layout.
2. Update the constraints in code on orientation changing, you may check if the UI element is beyond the screen and move it to new line and update later items accordingly.

First one is preferred.